# execution management

Tags: vb.net

I started using VB just a few days ago (programming in general). Now I made some interesting things, but am stuck on just 1.

I have multiple timers that counts down their own specific times.
Once the timer runs out, the program executes another .exe for each timer.
But I'm wondering what would be the smartest way to say, 'Queue' exe's when one is already running, Queue all the others until the current once's process doesn't exist. Then execute the next.....so it will keep going.

But my only problem is, how will the program know which one to execute next and delete the previously completed one from the queue?
Also does something that can handle this exist? Or would I have to make one from scratch?

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, "que" is Spanish for "what".  A series of items to be processed in order is a "queue".  As for your question, the word is your answer.  The .NET Framework includes the `Queue` class and the generic `Queue(Of T)` class.

Comment: Timer programming - "brilliant"

Comment: LOL, my bad about the que/queue thing. But anyways, thanks for the replies and info. will help me finish my first program. Thanks!